# How is this graph decomposable?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

[image]

I am looking at an exercise regarding decomposable graph. Above is an undirected graph. I know one necessary and sufficient condition for a decomposable graph is that any cycles of lengths $\geq4$ are chordal. Isn't it quite obvious that the circle 2-4-5-7 is not chordal?

In the answer, it only writes that the cycles 3-5-6-7 and 1-3-5-7-4-2 possess chords. Then, it suddenly jumps to the conclusion that this graph is decomposable. Don't we need to check other circles of length $\geq 4$?

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you mean to say that any cycle of length $>3$ is chordal?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, I do mean that. It should be greater or equal to 4.

Comment: I don't understand the answer at all.  As you say, the graph is clearly not chordal.

Comment: These lecture notes give this specific graph as an example of a prime graph (having no proper decomposition): http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~steffen/teaching/cimpa/decomp.pdf

Comment: @saulspatz So, in your opinion, this graph is also not decomposable. Right? If that's the case, I shall notify the person who provided the false answer.

Comment: Yes, I don't think it's decomposable.